# Get percentage of string in table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get the precentage of a string in a table, but I don't know how to filter the string after counting and than dividing it.
I tried this because I found it online, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT 
    table.column1, 
    COUNT(table1.column1) 
WHERE table1.column1 LIKE "String" AS countString
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.column1 / (SELECT COUNT(table1.column1) AS CountAll);
```

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY.

Comment: I dont quit know what u mean with that. Could you maybe provide a fixed version of my code

Comment: A [mcve] would help. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it:

```
SELECT 
    table1.column1, 
    COUNT(table1.column1) / (SELECT COUNT(table.column1) AS CountAll
                             FROM table1) AS PercentString  
FROM table1 
WHERE table1.column1 = 'String'
GROUP BY table1.column1;
```

Thanks for the help <3